# Matching select outputs with where clause statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query template

```
SELECT id 
FROM offers 
WHERE description LIKE "%X1%" 
OR description LIKE "%X2%" 
OR ... description LIKE "%X999%"
```

The where clause is constructed via a for loop based on the following object template

```
[
{index: 0, values: ["X1", "X2", "X3"]},
{index: 1, values: ["X4", "X5"]},
.
.
.
{index: N, values: ["X997", "X998", "X999"]}
]
```

There could be common X values shared by different objects in this array.

Basically, I find all the rows from the `offers` table that match the values coming from this array. However, I could not figure out how to map the output of the sql query to the index values of the request object.

Is there was a way to echo the value used in the where clause at the select section? If I could insert the index at the where clause as a dummy value and output it at the select section somehow... I'd appreciate your guidance on this.

Many thanks

Comment: If you could write the index to a temporary table or a cte, this could be done with an inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CASE statement in your SELECT clause to return the index along with the id for each matched row:

Try the below and see if it works, example:

```
SELECT id,
  CASE
    WHEN description LIKE '%X1%' THEN 0
    WHEN description LIKE '%X2%' THEN 0
    WHEN description LIKE '%X3%' THEN 0
    WHEN description LIKE '%X4%' THEN 1
    WHEN description LIKE '%X5%' THEN 1
    -- Add more cases here...
    ELSE -1
  END as `index`
FROM offers
WHERE description LIKE '%X1%'
OR description LIKE '%X2%'
OR description LIKE '%X3%'
OR description LIKE '%X4%'
OR description LIKE '%X5%'
-- Add more conditions here...
```